# How to derive all KKT points of a parametric optimization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic, parametric-functions

Suppose we have a symbolic optimization problem where all parameters and decision variables are nonnegative like the following problem. I would be thankful to know if there is any method to find all (potential) KKT points.

Here, $p$ is a decision variable and all others are positive parameters.

$$
\begin{align}
\underset{p>0}{\max}  Q(p)(p-k)+R(p)(f+r-p)\\
Q(p)=Qr(p)+Qk(p)\\
Qk(p)=1-\frac{p-f-\theta(\alpha+\beta)}{\theta(1-\beta)}\\
Qr(p)=\frac{p-f-\theta(\alpha+\beta)}{\theta(1-\beta)}-\frac{p+\frac{1-m}{m}f-(\alpha+\beta)}{1-\beta}\\
R(p)=(1-m)*Qr(p)\\
Qk(p),Qr(p)\ge0\\
p\le f+(1+\alpha)\theta\\ 
p\ge\frac{f \mu}{m(1-\theta)} \text{(rhs. is positive)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable pictures of text and equations.  Instead typeset in *MathJax*.

Comment: At first, I wrote equations in LaTeX format, but I faced an error and then I uploaded its picture.

Comment: Well, then, fix the error!

Comment: Actually copy-pastable Mathematica input would be preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the lagrangian `L` which follows,

```
Qk[p_] := 1 - (p - f - theta (alpha + beta))/theta/(1 - beta)
Qr[p_] := (p - f - theta (alpha + beta))/
theta/(1 - beta) - (p + (1 - m)/m f - (alpha + beta))/(1 - beta)
R[p_] := (1 - m) Qr[p]
Q[p_] := Qr[p] + Qk[p]

obj = Q[p] (p - k) + R[p] (f + r - p)

L = obj + l1 (p - f mu/m/(1 - theta) - s1^2) 
        + l2 (p - f - (1 + alpha) theta + s2^2)
        + l3 (Qk[p] - s3^2)
        + l4 (Qr[p] - s4^2)
```

here, `l1, l2, l3, l4` are generic lagrange multipliers and `s1, s2, s3, s4` are slack variables to transform the inequalities into equivalent equations.

The potential KKT points, are the stationary points for `L`. Those points can be calculated as follows:

```
grad = Grad[L, {p, l1, l2, l3, l4, s1, s2, s3, s4}]
sols = Solve[grad == 0, {p, l1, l2, l3, l4, s1, s2, s3, s4}]
results = Union[{obj, p, l1, l2, l3, l4, s1^2, s2^2, s3^2, s4^2} /. sols]
```

and we will consider to qualify, only the points with `s1^2 >= 0 && s2^2 >= 0  &&  s3^2 >= 0 && s4^2 >= 0`

Comment: I really appreciate.

Comment: Based on the results, ` p = f +(1 + alpha) theta` is not a KKT point, but based on the paper that I am studying, it seems that this point is a KKT point, too. How can I verify it? Thanks

Comment: The potential KKT values are the elements of `resultst = (results//Transpose)[[2]]` . Applying some numerical values to the symbolic parameters can be helpful to choose the feasible KKT points.